# WM_ACTIVATE and WM_SYSCOMMAND message equivalents for X11

Tags: c++, x11

I am currently porting a game engine from win32 to linux and was wondering about retrieving messages from the x window. As I stated in the topic I am searching for a way to intercept window messages that trigger screen saver/screen lock and minimized/maximized state, because I want to pause the rendering loop in those occations.

I guess it's something I have to manually tell X that I am interested in some particular client events and set them using the `XSetWMProtocols()`?
I'd appreciate some directions of what I have to look out for.

Comment: Use a toolkit such as Qt or gtk.

Comment: That's not an answer worth considering since I wont do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ScreenSaverSelectInput` request / `ScreenSaverNotify` event from [screen saver extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/scrnsaverproto/saver.txt)

Comment: It works, not like a charm, but it does. Do you have a solution to get notified when the program gets minimized, too? That would be brilliant :)

Comment: most reliable - watch for StructureNotify ( fired whenever your window is resized ). If you know that window manager is EWMH-compliant - watch PropertyNotify and check [_NET_WM_STATE](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472615568) property change

Comment: + maybe `MapNotify` / `UnmapNotify` events. Usually minimized == unmapped

Comment: That's some decent advice, thanks! I'll try that out.